# Finding the mean length of an array in a string Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am a student VERY new to python and I have no idea how to write a function that calculates the mean length of an array in a string. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
We are given

```
def mean_length(lst):
```

The tests are

```
assert mean_length(['fee','freed',free']) == 4
assert mean_length(['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon']) == 5.2
assert mean_length([]) == 0
```

I have tried

```
def mean_length(lst):
    x = lst.count(''.join(lst))
    y = int(3)
    mean = x / y
    return mean
```

Comment: One liner: `def mean_length(xs): return sum(len(x) for x in xs) / len(xs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just a one-liner:

```
def mean_length(l):
    return len(''.join(l))/len(l)
```

Here we are joining all the string in the list and counting the total number of characters and finally dividing it by the total number of elements in the `list`, thereby, giving us mean length of words.

Answer (score 2):

There’s already a function in the `statistics` library that can do this just map `len` to the list so you supply it the lengths.

```
l = ['fee','freed','free']
statistics.mean(map(len, l))
```

Comment: We are not allowed to use functions in the statistics library. But thank you for the input anyway.